# Useful script to manage buffer and window?

Tags: vimscript, buffers, vim-windows

I want to create a vertical split from current buffer for reference another file/the same file. After I've done with this split I don't want to see this buffer-for-reference in the split, but:

1. If this is a [No Name] buffer, then I'm happy to close this split.
2. If not, I would like to keep this split to keep the current layout of windows, so I can open up other buffer for reference with the same layout.

Further more, if this is the last window, I'm happy to delete current buffer whether or not it is a [No Name]-buffer.

How to achieve this function in vimscript?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script with assumption:

```
nnoremap <nowait><silent><expr> ∑                     "(YOUR_SHORT_CUT)
  \ (&filetype=="fern" <bar><bar> &filetype=="startify"
  \  <bar><bar> len(getbufinfo({'buflisted':1}))==1 && &filetype=="")? ":q<CR>":
    \ (winnr('$')==1)? ":bd<CR>":
      \ (&filetype=="")? ":bd<CR>": ":enew<CR>"
```

Assumption: Every time I do `:vsp` or `:sp`, it should create a new [No Name]-buffer, i.e.:

```
nnoremap <nowait><expr> <C-W><C-H>
    \ ":vsp<CR>".(&filetype==""? ":enew<CR>": "")
nnoremap <nowait><expr> <C-W><C-J>
    \ ":sp<CR><C-W><C-J>".(&filetype==""? ":enew<CR>": "")
nnoremap <nowait><expr> <C-W><C-K>
    \ ":sp<CR>".(&filetype==""? ":enew<CR>": "")
nnoremap <nowait><expr> <C-W><C-L>
    \ ":vsp<CR><C-W><C-L>".(&filetype==""? ":enew<CR>": "")
```

The scripts can:

1. If the filetype is MENU / DRAWER: since no buffer for them, use `:q`.
2. If it is the last [No Name]-buffer: at this situation we want to quit vim, use `:q`.
3. If only one window left: we can delete the buffer without destroy the window-layout, use `:bd`.
4. If there are many windows:

   - If it is [No Name]-buffer, by assumption every split create a new [No Name] buffer, so no need to worry about closing multiple [No Name]-buffers at the same time to destroy the layout, use `:bd`.
   - Otherwise, it's the buffer with which you're done, just `:enew` and keep the buffer you're done, so no possible to destroy layout(s) when it might also on other split(s).

In short: we only `:bd` when there is no layout(only one window left) anymore.

Feature: By holding `∑` you will close all of them and exit Vim.

---

Example:

[image]

Comment: Hi @job_start if you are satisfied with the solution maybe could you validate it such that the question could rest.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt It's probably just nonsense now, since after a year(oh wait it's two) I have changed a lot of my config. I will update it later.